# How can i write this query with gorm?

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

i want to write this query with gorm

```
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM (select distinct on(t1.number) t1.number ,t1.id from "tbl_phone_books" as t1                                                             
  WHERE (customer_id = 100)) as phone LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

i wrote this code but it didn't work correctly:

```
Db.Debug().
    Model(models.TblPhoneBook{}).
    Select("distinct on(number) number,id).
    Where("customer_id = ? , customerId).
    Offset(offset).
    Limit(5).
    Count(&response)
```

Comment: Your query is syntactically incorrect. Could please fix it, or supply a query that would successfully run? or explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: no in sql i get result

Comment: If you have the query, why do you want to use generate it?

Comment: i dont want use script i wanna use it with gorm

Comment: GORM literally gives you no advantage in this case. All it does is make your code harder to write (as you're experiencing)

Comment: I agree with @JonathanHall, I think you should just use that query directly, and then use GORM to scan the results back into a struct.

Comment: I'm new on backend is it better to use Gorm in code or sql script function on data base?

Answer (score 0):

`db.Table("tbl_phonebooks").Select("distinct on(number) number, id").Where("customer_id = ?", 100).Group("number, id").Limit(5).Offset(0).Count(&count)`